# How to change color of button ic CSS

Tags: html, css, colors

I can't change color of a button in CSS.

If I use color or background-color or border-color it wont change the color of the button.

```
<button id="b">Home</button>

#b {
  Color: green;
  Background-Color: green;
  Border-Color: green;
}
```

How can I change the color of the button ?

Comment: Can you post you problem with an example ?

Comment: @bhansa Of course

Comment: ## Example ##  HTML: `<button id="b">Home</button>`  CSS `#b { Color: green; Background-Color: green; Border-Color: green;  }`

Comment: `background-color` = color of the button

Answer (score 2):

```css
#demo{
  color:blue;
  background-color:#0ab;
  border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<button id="demo">Button</button>
```

There are typos in your code.
You are using Color instead of **color** and so on. Please remove the typos.

Better start reading more about [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)